# Automatically update innerText of a div using Query?

Tags: jquery

I have a div like so:

```
<div id="time_text"></div>
```

I want to be able to retrieve the current time automatically every seconds (or few seconds) then update the innertext of that div with the current time retrieved. I found this function online that updates the time:

```
function getTime(offset){
 var now = new Date();
 var hour = 60*60*1000;
 var min = 60*1000;
 return new Date(now.getTime() + (now.getTimezoneOffset() * min) + (offset * hour));
}
```

How would I use that function to get the time automatically, then update the innerText of my div?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use setInterval to update your time

```
  setInterval(function () {
       var str= new Date(now.getTime() + (now.getTimezoneOffset() * min) + (offset * hour));

        $('#time_text').html(str);
    }, 5000);
```

This will update the time in every 5 seconds

Here is the working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/8Av5d/11/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but dont reinvent the wheel. Someone had already wrote an easy way to do this.

[EasyDate jQuery plugin](http://easydate.parshap.com/)